# Getting error " not enough arguments in call to s.statsd.SendLoop" when running "go build" command

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-go

I'm trying to run go build command for my project but it exits with below error.

```
alpha@GHOST-RIDER:~/GoWorkspace/src/github.com/hyperledger/firstproject$ go build
# github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/internal/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/operations
../fabric-sdk-go/internal/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/operations/system.go:227:23: not enough arguments in call to s.statsd.SendLoop
    have (<-chan time.Time, string, string)
    want (context.Context, <-chan time.Time, string, string)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per code fabric is using the different version of this library: `github.com/go-kit/kit/metrics/statsd`. If you follow the `System` struct's `statsd` attribute, you can reach the reference on imports.

In master branch of this lib, `SendLoop` function requires **4** attributes, so that's the root cause. So this causes error when you compile on your local environment.

I had the same issue and worked around it by checking out a tag of library as below:

```
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/go-kit/kit
git fetch --tags
git checkout v0.8.0
```

Comment: Doesn`t work in my Case. Also tried latest v.0.10.0

Answer (score 2):

found a solution on the hyperledger-fabric-go-sdk group chat.

Add `context.Background()` in `s.statsd.SendLoop` like below

```
s.statsd.SendLoop(context.Background(), s.sendTicker.C, network, address)
```

in `fabric-sdk-go/internal/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/operations/system.go` file at line 227.

Comment: I think, editing the fabric source code must be avoided.

Comment: Yep, but only that works correctly. Or, you need to change your fabric-sdk version (update it). But we are using fabric-sdk-go@v0.0.0-20190306235112-f198238ee7da now

Answer (score 1):

I had a same issue, my solution worked and don't need edit fabric source code.

specify github.com/go-kit/kit to v0.8.0, modify go.mod:

```
replace github.com/go-kit/kit => github.com/go-kit/kit v0.8.0  // you specific version

require (
... ...

    // Maybe other version, go mod tidy update automatically, don't care it. 
    github.com/go-kit/kit v0.9.0 // indirect  

... ...
)
```

then it worked.